# Solve this PDE $yu_x-xu_y=2xyu$ (problem with general solution)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential, characteristics

Find the general solution of the part differential equation $$yu_x-xu_y=2xyu$$

So $$\frac{dx}{y}=-\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{du}{2xy}$$

Which in turn implies $$\int xdx =- \int ydy \Rightarrow \frac{x^{2}}{2}=-\frac{y^{2}}{2}+C_1 \Rightarrow C_1=\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})$$

Now I don't know how to get second solution. I try in this way: $$\frac{du}{2xy}=\frac{xdx+ydy}{xy-xy} \Rightarrow \frac{du}{2xy}=\frac{xdx+ydy}{0}$$

But I don't know does this equation make sense. And how to solve this? Like this?: $$xdx+ydy=0/ \cdot 2$$ $$2xdx+2ydy=0 \Rightarrow d(x^{2}+y^{2})=0 \Rightarrow C_{2}=x^{2}+y^{2} \Rightarrow u(x,y)=F(\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2}),x^{2}+y^{2})$$ I don't think it makes sense, and when I put this code to wolfram alpha
`y*D[u[x,y],x]-x*D[u[x,y],y]=2x*y*u` -> https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y*D%5Bu%5Bx%2Cy%5D%2Cx%5D-x*D%5Bu%5Bx%2Cy%5D%2Cy%5D%3D2x*y*u

I get this general solution $$u(x,y)=e^{x^{2}} \cdot C_1(\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2}))$$
It has first component calculated by me, but I don't know how we get $e^{x^{2}}\cdot ..  $

Please help me solve this PDE or give me a hint.

Answer (score 3):

$$yu_x-xu_y=2xyu$$

There is a mistake in your Charpit-Lagrange charasteristic ODEs. After correction of the third term :

$$\frac{dx}{y}=-\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{du}{2xyu}$$
A first characteristic equation comes for solving $\frac{dx}{y}=-\frac{dy}{x}$ :
$$x^2+y^2=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{du}{2xyu}$ :
$$u\,e^{-x^2}=c_2$$

The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$u\,e^{-x^2}=F(x^2+y^2)$$
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=e^{x^2}F(x^2+y^2)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function to be determined according to some boundary condition.

LATTER ADDITION. Answer to one of the comments.

An alternative method to find the first characteristic equation (what ever the third term be $\frac{du}{2xyu}$ or $\frac{du}{2xyu}$ or other :

$$\frac{dx}{y}=-\frac{dy}{x}$$
from elementary property of equal fractions with any $A$ and $B$ not both nul :
$$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{-dy}{x}=\frac{A\,dx+B(-dy)}{A\,y+B\,x}$$
With $A=x$ and $B=-y$
$$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{-dy}{x}=\frac{x\,dx+(-y)(-dy)}{x\,y+(-y)\,x}=\frac{\frac12d(x^2+y^2)}{0}$$
This implies $\quad d(x^2+y^2)=0\quad$ thus $\quad x^2+y^2=C$.

NOTE :

If instead of $yu_x-xu_y=2xyu$ the PDE was

$$yu_x-xu_y=2xy$$

$$\frac{dx}{y}=-\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{du}{2xy}$$
First characteristic equation :
$$x^2+y^2=c_1$$
Second characteristic equation from solving $\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{du}{2xy}$ :
$$du-2xdx=0\quad\implies\quad u-x^2=c_2$$
General solution on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ leading to :
$$u(x,y)=x^2+F(x^2+y^2)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function. The general solution of the second PDE without exponential term is very different from the general solution of the first PDE which involves an exponential term.

Comment: Ok so $\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{du}{2xyu} \Rightarrow \int (2x)dx=\int \frac{du}{u} \Rightarrow e^{x^{2}+C_2}=u \Rightarrow e^{x^{2}} \cdot C_2=u \Rightarrow C_2=u \cdot e^{-x^{2}}$

Comment: What If I calculate like this $\int (2x)dx=\int \frac{du}{u} \Rightarrow x^{2}=ln(u \cdot C_2) \Rightarrow C_2=\frac{1}{e^{-x^{2}} \cdot u}$ or first component like this $\int (x)dx=-\int (y)dy \Rightarrow \frac{x^{2}}{2}+C_1=-\frac{y^{2}}{2} \Rightarrow C_1=-\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})$ I get different solution?, what is the rule that after integration operation we set Constant on the y-side (calculate first component) and x-side (calculate second component)?

Comment: The apparently different solutions are equivalent one to another since the constants are arbitrary : You can take $c$ or $-2c$ or $c/2$ or else.  All are arbitrary thus equivalent.

Comment: One can write $f(x^2+y^2)$ or $F(-\frac12(x^2+y^2))$ or $\Phi(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})$ or any other function with $(x^2+y^2)$ into it because all are arbitrary functions.

Comment: Of course the above comments are true if no boundary condition is specified. But this isn't true If some valid boundary condition is specified : the constants and/or functions are no longer arbitrary and the solution is likely to be determined.

Comment: Ok at the end, to get your $x^{2}+y^{2}=C_1$ you calculated $\frac{dx}{y}=-\frac{dy}{x}$ like this $\frac{dx}{y}=-\frac{dy}{x} |\cdot 2 \Rightarrow x^{2}=-y^{2}+C_1 \Rightarrow C_1=x^{2}+y^{2}$ or how?

Comment: And this is really the last question -> If my solution for "mistake case" was correct, I mean $$\frac{du}{2xy}=\frac{xdx+ydy}{xy-xy}=\frac{xdx+ydy}{0}$$ Then $$xdx+ydy=0 \Rightarrow xdx+ydy=|\cdot 2\Rightarrow 2xdx+2ydy=0$$  So $$C_2=x^{2}+y^{2}$$ and power rule for this is $xdx=\frac{dx^{2}}{2}$?

Comment: Doesn't matter $\frac{du}{2xy}$ or $\frac{du}{2xyu}$ the first characteristic equation is $x^2+y^2)=C$. See the addition at the end of my main answer.

Comment: Your solution for the "mistaked case" was not correct. See the note again added at the end of my main answer.

Comment: Why not correct? Can you explaint, which part $xdx+ydy=0 \Rightarrow 2xdx+2ydy=0 \Rightarrow C_2=x^{2}+y^{2}$ or "and power rule for this is $xdx=\frac{dx^{2}}{2}$" ?

Comment: Of course this is correct for the first characteristic equation but not for the second.